# how to extract the initials of first name and middle name with surname as it is in java without using split()

Tags: java

Cannot use Split function, please help...

suppose input = `SACHIN RAMESH TENDULKAR` all in caps.

output = `Tendulkar.S.R`

the code i tried is with string array is there any other option?-

```
import java.util.*;
public class substr {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] array = new String[3];
            System.out.println("Please enter first name,middle name and 
           last name in capital");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
                array[i] = s.nextLine();
            }
            char f=array[0].charAt(0);
            char m=array[1].charAt(0);
            char sn=array[2].charAt(0);
            String sn1="";
            for(int i=1;i<array[2].length();i++){
                char ch=array[2].charAt(i);
                if(ch>=65 && ch<90){
                    ch=(char)(ch+32);
                    }   
                    sn1+=ch;

                }
            System.out.println(sn+sn1+"."+f+"."+m); 
        }

}
```

Comment: You do realize that you use split() in your code?
How about you post what you tried which goes with your question and then we help?
This isn't a place for do-my-homework questions

Comment: yeah i have used split() @namsnath

Comment: your questions asks for "without using split()" and it would make sense if you actually tried something and showed us what you did that follows those requirements instead of asking us questions you should be asking a teacher or looking for in a textbook

Comment: Use regex pattern matcher

Comment: @namsnath this is the code which i have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Substr {

public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter First Name, Middle Name and Last Name");
       String fullName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase(); // convert input to UPPERCASE
       while(fullName.charAt(fullName.length()-1)==' '){ // remove all spaces at the end of the input because it may cause problem
            fullName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.length()-1);
       }
       while(fullName.charAt(0)==' '){ // remove all spaces at the beginning of the input because it may cause problem
           fullName = fullName.substring(1, fullName.length());
       }

       String firstName = "", middleName ="", lastName ="";

       firstName = fullName.substring(0, fullName.indexOf(' ')); // the first name is from the beginning to the first occurrence of space 

       int noOfSpaces=0;
       for(int i=firstName.length(); i<fullName.length(); i++){// count the number of spaces after the first name in case user by mistake
                                                                                    // entered more than one space
            if (fullName.charAt(i)==' '){
                noOfSpaces++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
       }
       middleName = fullName.substring(firstName.length()+noOfSpaces, fullName.lastIndexOf(' ')); // the second name (remember we removed the spaces at the end)

       lastName = fullName.substring(fullName.lastIndexOf(' ')+1,fullName.length()); // the last name

        String customizedName = firstName + "." + middleName.charAt(0) + "." + lastName.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(customizedName); 
}
```

example (notice the on-purpose spaces before and after first name, after second name and after last name -> won't ruin the output):

```
Please enter First Name, Middle Name and Last Name
    Muhammad    Yahya   Almardeny
MUHAMMAD.Y.A
```

another example (normal):

```
Please enter First Name, Middle Name and Last Name
Muhammad Yahya Almardeny
MUHAMMAD.Y.A
```

Answer (score 1):

Because they enter all the info at the same time, you can only call `s.nextLine()` once. So your whole code has to be altered for this to work. Consider the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter first name, middle name and last name in capital");

String name = s.nextLine();    
char[] c = name.toCharArray();
char f, m = ' ', sn = ' ';

int index = 0;    
f = c[0];

for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
    if(c[i] == ' '){
        if(m == ' '){
            m = c[i+1];
        }else{
            index = i+1;
            sn = c[i+1];
            break;
        }
    }
}

String sn1 = "";    
for(int i = index; i < c.length; i++)        
    sn1 += String.valueOf(c[i]);

System.out.println(sn1 + "." + f + "." + sn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the charAt() to find the whitespace and then get the next character, maybe?